# Vector assignment to Dask array

Tags: matrix, slice, variable-assignment, dask

I'm trying to change the slice in Dask array row-wise and col-wise way:

```
from dask import array as da
A = da.from_array(np.zeros((3,3)))
A[[0,1,2], 0] = [1,2,3]
A.compute()
```

And I've got:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0.],
       [3., 0., 0.]])
```

But in row-wise way:

```
A = da.from_array(np.zeros((3,3)))
A[0,[0,1,2]] = [1,2,3]
A.compute()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Do You where the problem is? Or any other method to do this kind of assignment?

Comment: I think your two code snippets are the same?

Comment: I do see this different behavior though for `A[[0,1,2], 0] = [1,2,3]` getting your first result and your posted code giving the error

Comment: just reproduced this on `2022.01.0` and `2022.03.0` (latest)

Comment: I just edited your example to correct the duplicated snippet issue. this could be a live bug in dask. quickly looking through the open issues & PRs I don't see anything covering this. I do see that dask's `__setitem__` got a major refactor last year (see [issue #7392](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7392) and [PR #7393](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/7393)). I think you could file an issue with this and see if it's known or is a new bug.

Comment: also, when asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they include a ton of useful detail about where the bug happened and how that flows through the code

Comment: I agree with @MichaelDelgado that this might be a bug, I'd encourage you to [open an issue for this](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3ABug%2CType%3ANeeds+Triage&template=bug-report.md). :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this may be a bug, here are some workarounds to do the same operation:

- `A[0:1, [0,1,2]] = [1,2,3]`
- `A[0] = [1,2,3]`

Ref: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-assignment.html